# code to replace out token if blocks

Tags: replace

I need some code to replace out a token if block such as

myText = "some text. [IfIsFile:True]this is a file[EndIfIsFile:True] [IfIsFile:False]this is not a file[EndIfIsFile:False]. more text"

I am happy to call each if block separately (true then false)
I need to send in the 
function myReplace(text, token, Boolean if leave text or blank it) as string

I may call it as
myReplace(text, "[IfIsFile:True]", true)

and then 
myReplace(text, "[IfIsFile:False]", false)

results would be
"some text. this is a file. more text"

Comment: actually it could be called with start token and end token such as

myReplace(text, "[IfIsFile:True]",  "[EndIfIsFile:True]", true)

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried? SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I am using vb.net but I can get that from c# or vb.net. I am not looking for free code but a function someone has already written for the task. otherwise I am writing it out myself

Answer (score 0):

ok I thought this would be much harder but I was able to write it up. if anyone wants to post improved code - pls do

```
        Protected Function ReplaceIfToken(ByVal sText As String, ByVal startToken As String, ByVal endToken As String, ByVal bLeave As Boolean) As String
        Dim str As String = sText
        Dim iStart As Integer = 0
        Dim iEnd As Integer = 0
        iStart = InStr(str, startToken)
        iEnd = InStr(str, endToken)
        While iStart > 0
            Dim fullTokenText As String = str.Substring(iStart - 1, iEnd + endToken.Length - iStart)
            Dim fullTokenTextwoToken As String = fullTokenText.Replace(startToken, "").Replace(endToken, "")
            If bLeave Then
                str = str.Replace(fullTokenText, fullTokenTextwoToken)
            Else
                str = str.Replace(fullTokenText, "")
            End If
            iStart = InStr(str, startToken)
            iEnd = InStr(str, endToken)
        End While
        Return str
    End Function
```